# Pandas - Convert 2 string columns to booleans and combine

Tags: python, pandas, merge

you guys! I'm new to Pandas, and I'm kind of stumped on this issue here. I have 2 columns with text in them. I want to create a new column that is a binary representation of boolean values. The 2 columns should be converted to true if they have a value or false if they don't have a value. I've tried using notnull() and isnull(), but the empty values are resulting to True instead of False.

I want to take this:

```
    dicts = {"names": ["John", "Jill", "Michael"], "ages": ["8", " ", " "]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(dicts)
```

and turn it into this (where the null values evaluate to false:

```
---------------------
|  names   |  ages  |
----------------------
   True    |   True
   True    |   False
   True    |   False

Then merge them (where the True values are dominant):

--------------------------------
|  names   |  ages  |  combined |
---------------------------------
   True    |  True  |   True
   True    |  False |   True
   True    |  False |   True

The final product should look like this:

--------------------------------
|  names   |  ages  |  combined |
---------------------------------
   John    |    8   |     1
   Jill    |        |     1
  Michael  |        |     1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why the last one is zero?

Comment: You're right...I'm half asleep. I must have made a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
df['combined'] = df.fillna(' ').ne(' ').any(axis=1).astype(int)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     names ages  combined
0     John    8         1
1     Jill              1
2  Michael              1
```

Comment: It worked great! Thank you so much! I had been struggling for an hour or so, trying to figure that out.

Comment: @NoSoyTuMadre Glad I could help